# Ruby on Rails: parameter passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model-view-controller

I have my application with resources `Users` and `Articles`. On the URL `localhost/users/1` i get all the articles for user 1. On the URL `localhost/users/2` I get all the articles for user 2 etc. On those URL-s I also have the functions to edit/remove/add articles for a given `User`. And such URL is, for example if I `edit` article 2, `localhost/articles/2/edit`. So it does not send the `User` ID, but only the `Article` ID.

Now I want to be able to add/remove/edit article for a given user, in such way that after this action is done i get redirected back to the list of this users articles. So I want to be redirected to the URL `localhost/users/1` if I edited/updated/removed and clicked `Save`.

So I have a following sequence of actions:

1) go to the given user URL (URL takes me to: `localhost/users/1`)

2) edit article 2 for this user (URL takes me to: `localhost/articles/2/edit`)

3) click Save (I want URL now to take me back to: `localhost/users/1`)

My `Show` controller for the `User` works fine.

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @articles = Article.all
end
```

My `Update` controller for the `Article` I cant figure.

```
def update

    # I want something like this to find the user, How do I access the user from which the action is going
    #@user = User.find(params[:id]) 
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update_attributes(allowed_params)
        #redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

So this clearly isnt working. Any advice?

Update: `Show` view for the user.

```
    <h2> <p> Articles for user: <%= @user.email %> </p> </h2>

<%= link_to 'Add article', new_article_path %>

<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <p>
        <b>Title: </b> <%= article.title %> <br />
        <b>Content: </b> <br /> <%= article.content %> <br />
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %> | 
        <%= link_to 'Delete', article, method: :delete %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Don't articles have an associated user?

Comment: In theory they do, but Im not sure how to implement this. Im new to RoR. It would save me from a lot of trouble tho.

Comment: At mininum, you should add `belongs_to :user` to Article class. Also read the rails guide on [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Okay, I added this to my model, how do I now access it?

Comment: You may have to add `has_many :articles` to User class too and then use `@articles = @user.articles` in User controller

Comment: Well the main problem is that I dont know the User ID in update/delete/add action. So i cant have @user variable.

Comment: As @sergio mentioned, If you set the associations correctly you should be able to get user by `@user = @article.user` in your update method for Article controller

Comment: @Whizzil: did you read the guide too?

Comment: I did, and I set associations like this: Article belongs_to :user, User has_many :articles. Now I have in update for Article controller @.article = Article.new(allowed_params);
  @.user = @.article.user; but it gives an error that ID = nil.

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil. The problem is that User ID is never passed...

Comment: For example in Articles create I have: @.user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @.article = Article.new(allowed_params). And the problem is "Couldn't find User with 'id'=".

Answer (score 0):

You can just [redirect](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) `:back` to whatever web page the user was on with the following:

```
redirect_to :back
```

So you end up with this:

```
def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update_attributes(allowed_params)
        redirect_to :back
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Comment: this just stays on the same page... I hit Save and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Following your sequence:

1) With the route `/users/:id` you should be able to access a single user and not a given user's articles. If you want to get the latter, you'd better use `/users/:user_id/articles`.

2) If you want to perform an action on a given user's article, let's say to edit it, the REST route for that is `/users/:user_id/articles/:id/edit`

Defining these routes in `routes.rb` is very easy because they're following the REST convention:

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles
end
```

Your models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So that in the `index` **action** of the `Articles` controller, you'll be able to get all articles of a given user:

```
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @articles = @user.articles
end
```

If you'd like to update a single article of a given user:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update_attributes(allowed_params)
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Comment: If I did this, now the routes are changed. I get error "undefined method `article_path'" in here: <%= form_for @.article do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :title %> <br />
 <%= f.text_field :title %> <br />

Comment: This messed up routes in my views.

Comment: Yes, probably some changes should be done in your views as well. Can you post them?

Comment: But if you don't mind, post them as an edit to your original question for clarity.

Comment: The code seems ok, but I think the problem is the naming. The update should be `index`, not `show`. One uses `show` action when it concerns a single item.

Answer (score 0):

You want something called [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :articles #-> url.com/users/:user_id/articles/:id
end
```

--

This will give you a set of *nested* routes for `creating/reading/updating/destroying` your `articles` under your `user`.

As mentioned in the answer by `zoro`, you'll want to ensure that your `articles` are associated to your `users` with a [`has_many/belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) relationship:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles
end

#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This way, each `@article` will have an `@article.user` associative object, which can be called using the following:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_user

   def index
      @articles = @user.articles
   end

   def edit
      @article = @user ? @user.articles.find(params[:id]) : Article.find(params[:id])
   end

   def update
      @article = @user ? @user.articles.find(params[:id]) : Article.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to user_articles_path(@user) if @article.update article_params
   end

   private

   def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(......)
   end

   def set_user
      @user = User.find params[:user_id] if params[:user_id] #-> allows you to use this without nesting
   end
end
```

The view could be as follows:

```
#app/views/articles/index.html.erb
<% if @articles %>
   <% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <%= article.title %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `user_id` parameter in each of article you just add this:

```
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  if @article.update_attributes(allowed_params)
    redirect_to user_path(@article.user)
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

If you don't have `user_id` parameter in your article. Please add this:

```
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.user_id = current_user.id
  if @article.update_attributes(allowed_params)
    redirect_to user_path(@article.user)
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

or

```
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.user_id = allowed_params[:user_id]
  if @article.update_attributes(allowed_params)
    redirect_to user_path(@article.user)
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

or you can add hidden_field in you form to set user_id

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>
```

I hope this help you